# Turning quadratic-time program into a linear-time one with help of monoid?

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, time-complexity

While I was reading a paper dedicated to Yoneda lemma and it's relationship with profunctors optics, I've encountered following statement:

> ...Cayley’s
>   Theorem for monoids (which is the trick that enables the use of an accumulating parameter, which
>   can often turn a quadratic-time program into a linear-time one)...

The part I am interested in is `the trick ... quadratic-time... into a linear-time one`. How does it work?

P.S. I am familiar with monoids and common math notation for them, so feel free to use it, if necessary or stick to Haskell.

Comment: You could have provided some links like https://patternsinfp.wordpress.com/2018/08/14/folds-on-lists/ or to the paper you cite, https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/proyo.pdf

Comment: If you read the paper, did you get to section 3.3 where exactly that quote is explained? The quadratic time algorithm is the reversal of a (linked I think) list, while the linear time algorithm is the reversal of some endomorphism representing the list. For details see https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/john-hughes/lists.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the original paper by H. Bird, the leading example for that claim is list reversal for simply-linked lists, which can be defined as

```
reverse([a : x]) = append(reverse x, a)
```

In a direct implementation, to append `a` to the reverse of the tail `x` requires `n-1` lookup operations to find the end, and the operations count for `reverse x`, so that the total effort is `(n-1)+...+2+1=n*(n-1)/2`.

The linear implementation uses the asymmetric complexity of the `append` operation as `append(x,y)` has a cost proportional to the length of `x`, while the length of `y` does not play any role. As a partial operation, `append` is an endomorphism on the space of lists, `append(x) y = append(x,y)`. 
Now represent the reversed list as the result of a concatenation of these endomorphisms

```
reverse([a1,a2,...,an])=append(an) ... append(a2) append(a1) []
```

from which the list reconstruction is a linear cost operation. The previously quadratic "main" cost is "hidden" in the management of the operations stack. However, this in the end is not really needed as the reconstruction of the resulting list can start with the extraction of the first element. This needs the "accumulating element", in the same wild pseudo-code

```
reverse(x) = reverse_recursion(x,[])
```

where

```
reverse_recursion([a : x], y) = reverse_recursion(x, [a : y])
```

with

```
reverse_recursion([], y) = y
```